# Business logic class, using a dictionary instead of properties

Tags: php, properties, business-logic

I have a business logic class, which holds all the data of an user. The class should be able to insert/fetch/update/delete the user from a mysql database.

I started creating all the properties like username,password,email, etc... but the I realized that having a single dictionary containing all the properties is more convenient, because I frequently need to concert the user object to a dictionary or a string, and I need to hold key-value pairs. So I've written the class this way:

```
class User {
    public $parameters;
    public function __construct($parameters) 
    {
        $this->parameters= $parameters;
    }
    public function __get($property) {
        return $parameters[$property];
    }
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. The behaviour I want is:

```
$user= new User($params);
echo user.username;  // Searches in the parameters for the field "username"
```

Is possibile to do this?

**Edit**

With $user->username I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: parameters in /Library/WebServer/Documents/Cinema/blogics/user.php on line 10

Line 10 is the user __get method.

Comment: It helps if you use the object operator `->` rather than the concatenation operator `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `$this->parameters[$property]` instead of `$parameters[$property]` in the getter
- call it `$user->username`
- `$parameters` should be private to keep the encapsulation

**In code**

```
class User {
    private $parameters; // should be private (encapsulation)
    public function __construct($parameters)
    {
        $this->parameters= $parameters;
    }
    public function __get($property) {
        return $this->parameters[$property]; // instead of $parameters[$property]
    }
}

$params = array(
  "username" => "John Doe",
  "age" => 33
);

$user = new User($params);
echo $user->username; // -> instead of .
```

Comment: "private" $parameters is a good point, since you're using getters&setters

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `username` as `class` variable.

```
  public $username;
```

Then you can call username with user object as

```
   $user->username;
```

For more details about oops with PHP, you can check this link
http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/

Comment: Even this way it doesn't work, it's not recognized as a property.